# Can I use MYSQL database of X provider in the file hosting provided by Y hosting provider

Tags: mysql, hosting

I am having account on Godaddy.in , in that account i can create 25 databases.
I also have a hosting account on BigRock.in but it dont provide any MYSQL data base, it only provide file hosting , but i want to know whether i can connect to the database of the Godady.in in the file hosted on BigRock.in

Comment: Yes, if Godaddy allows external connections to their db. Otherwise, no.

Comment: I think you just park the domain, and point the nameservers to the mysql hosted account - but Godaddy will tell you what to do.

Comment: Hmm... I'm quite unsure, but you may ask their support team. I never try this way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be possible if you enable Direct Database Access - http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4978/connecting-remotely-to-shared-hosting-databases. But it is not a good practice because you will have some latency to load the data from one provider to another.